Cannot parallelize my code using parallel library
I'm having a lot of trouble trying to parallelize a code I had. Basically, this code introduces two new records into DB.
If the records you enter already exists, and are in error state, both are entered after sending the old one to historical. If these records aren´t in error state, they are discarded and, if these records doesnt exists previously, they are introduced directly.
To parallelize this code, I tried to fixed it creating a DBContext and a UnitOfWork per thread. But I still keeping find the same error:
A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. 
I can't see the problem, even more the solution, can you help me, please?
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2;

    Parallel.ForEach(excelRawList.SuccessRows, options, (excelRow) =>
    {
        using (var dbContext = new MyContext(
        new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
    .UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB"))
            .Options))
        {
            using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(dbContext))
            {
                try
                {
                    int? canBeInserted = await service3.CanBeInserted(excelRow.Id);
    
                    // canBeIserted could be 3 values: null (there is not previous record), 0 (there is a previous record and it is not an error),
                    // Id_value (there is a previous record but it was an error)
    
                    if (canBeInserted != 0)
                    {
                        if (!excelRow.Prorroga)
                        {
                            using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_timeoutTransaccion)))
                            {
                                unitOfWork.BeginTransaction(cts);
    
                                if (canBeInserted != null)
                                {
                                    service4.MoveToHistoric(unitOfWork, canBeInserted.Value, cts);
                                }
    
                                Entity2 entity2 = service3.Entity1ToEntity2(excelRow);
                                excelRow.entity2 = entity2;
    
                                unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity2>().Add(entity2);
                                unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity1>().Add(excelRow);
    
                                unitOfWork.SaveChanges(cts);
                                unitOfWork.CommitTransaction(cts);
    
                                if (entity2.Age == null)
                                {
                                   _logger.LogWarning("Age didnt find it");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
                        {
                            unitOfWork.Rollback();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            unitOfWork.Rollback();
                        }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                       excelRow.FK2= null;
                       _service1.Add(excelRow);
                  }
             }
             else
             {
                   excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError() { 
             }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError()
              {
                   Message = ex.InnerException.Message
              });
          }
        }
      }
    });

    public void MoveToHistoric(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, int Id, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        try
        {
            Entity1 entity1 = service1.Get(id);
            Entity2 entity2 = service2.Get(entity1.FK);
            Entity3 entity3 = _mapper.Map<Entity3>(entity1);
            Entity4 entity4 = _mapper.Map<Entity4>(entity2);
    
            unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity1>().Remove(entity1);
            unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity2>().Remove(entity2);
    
            await unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsyncLimite(cts);
    
            entity3.Entity4 = entity4;
            unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity4>().Add(entity4);
            unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity3>().Add(entity3);
    
            unitOfWork.SaveChanges(cts);
    
            return unitOfWork;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

Many Thanks

For just two records, wouldn't it make more sense to save them asynchronously, rather than trying to simulate concurrency that the database already has?  DbContext.AddAsync Method

Ah, I see you're already saving them asynchronously.  Parallelizing is unlikely to produce any additional benefit;  multiple threads are useful mostly for CPU-bound work, not I/O-bound work.

service3 & service1 seem to be doing database work, but I cant see them getting a dbContext or unitOfWork reference anywhere. Are you sure there is no long lived, shared, dbContext lurking in the background anywhere? I would also agree with Robert Harvey, it seem doubtful that this would give a significant performance advantage.

@RobertHarvey. Many thanks for helping here. There are two insertions, but in the worst case there are 4 insertions in DB and 2 removes. They are currently saved asynchronously. The problem arises when in this part Parallel.ForEach(excelRawList.SuccessRows.... There are 500 rows in excelRawList.SuccessRows. Which would be 3000 operations in DB. If I manage to parallelize with 2 threads, I will reduce the time a little less than half. I will also test the general performance of the system with 3 and 4 threads. Many thanks again.

@RobertHarvey. Yep, I was trying to make it works and then I would change to synchronous. But, right, I changed all asynchronous call to synchronous and now I am receiving the next error creating the context: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. It looks easy but Now, I cannot think clearly. I have updated my question to provide you the last update.  I have configure properly the context on program.cs and properly injected. Many Thanks again.

@JonasH. I have updated my question to provide you the last update, Now the code is completely synchronous. Besides, my idea, is creating a dbcontext per iteration/thread so they dont share that context. I hoped to fix it in that way but, now, I am receiving something that looks like a dummy error but I cannot figure out. The error is: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.  I have configure properly the context on program.cs and properly injected. Many Thanks

Well, solved. It was easy, but now, I am still receiving the very beginning error, when my code was asynchronous. "A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext" Still completely lost.

My point is service3.CanBeInserted(excelRow.Id) presumably needs to check the database to figure out if the ID exist. How does it do that without a database context? Is service3, and all the other services, guaranteed to be threadsafe? Neither is obvious from the provided examples.

@JonasH. Oh, you are right. Never thought about CanBeInserted... I use the common context belong to the UnitOfWork object and it is working for now. So, many many thanks. How can I rate your help and answer? Cheers

My guess would be that await service3.CanBeInserted(excelRow.Id), or one of the other service classes, look something like this:
public class Service3{
    MyContext dbContext;
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    public Service3(string connectionString){
       dbContext = new MyContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
              .UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionString))
              .Options);
       unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(dbContext);
   }
   public int? CanBeInserted(int id){
   ...
   }
}

This will cause issues when used in a parallel loop since it will allow multiple calls to be done in parallel on the same db context, exactly as your error message says.
The approach I'm most used to is to create a unit of work object per call in any service classes, i.e.
public class Service3{
    IUnitOfWorkFactory unitFactory;
    public Service3(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitFactory) => this.unitFactory = unitFactory;
   public int? CanBeInserted(int id){
       using(var unitOfWork = unitFactory.Create()){
           ...
       }
   }
}

Where the IUnitOfWorkFactory.Create is responsible for creating a new DbContext and UnitOfWork object.
Another approach that might be more suitable for your specific use case would be to take the unit of work as a parameter:
public class Service3{
   public int? CanBeInserted(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, int id){
       ...
   }
}

Both options should remove the possibility of a db context being used concurrently from multiple threads.
